# How do I delete a custom deck on the ipad version of hearthstone?

Tags: ios, hearthstone

On the PC it's easy to delete decks but I can't figure out how to delete a deck from the ipad version.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your collection .Then you tap on one of the existing custom decks that you have made. It will show you all the cards that you have drafted. You then have to tap another time for it to show a little side bar which shows you your mana curve aswell as give you options to rename or delete the deck.